# PHP Form - continued issues

Tags: php

how do I sterilize the coding for a very basic php order form connected to an html page? At the moment, the coding works, but I'm concerned that, as is, the coding enables potential spammers to have a field day with my site and email address. I'm not really sure exactly what sterilizing my code means/would entail, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i assume you hard codded the email address so they can only send spam to one person?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a [captcha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) to your form.

Answer (score 0):

You might have seen the word `sanitize` which is means that you need to beware the user. Always assume the users are evil super-hackers out to get you.

Anything can be submitted to your server, so you can't trust that anything you did to the webpage or expected from it will remain. `Sanitizing` input means escaping any potential html or SQL or checking for anything else before working with it.

Relevant:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)